# jenkins error when update Github repository

Tags: git, github, jenkins

Jenkins 2.46.3
git plugin 3.60
GitHub API Plugin 1.89
GitHub plugin 1.28.0

when I update branch with build status ( although the status updated successfully ) I got the following error :

> 20:57:57 ERROR: [GitHub Commit Status Setter] - Server returned HTTP
>   response code: 201, message: 'Created' for URL

looks like only the latest github repositories got this error.

any idea ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

=> Upgrade [GitHub API Plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/github-api) to 1.90+

We got the same issue randomly and regardless which version of the plugin was used (deprecated or obsolete): see [NXBT-1987](https://jira.nuxeo.com/browse/NXBT-1987) where I refer to other links.
The cause appeared to be a change in GitHub API: they switched the format of some integers from 32 to 64 bits.
See [jenkinsci/github-api-plugin/pull/16](https://github.com/jenkinsci/github-api-plugin/pull/16) and [kohsuke/github-api/issues/387](https://github.com/kohsuke/github-api/issues/387).

Comment: I update the following plugins - git plugin 3.64 GitHub API Plugin 1.90 GitHub plugin 1.28.1 and it solve the problem

Answer (score 2):

The 200 range of status code are not errors. They indicate success. 201 in particular means some resource was successfully created.

Comment: Thanks for your answer , the problem with that is the build become unstable , I change my function to ignore those errors. The question is why it start to happens and NOT on all re repos ...